# Configure Amazon Cloud Front with Grails Web Application

Tags: grails, amazon-cloudfront

I am new on this way. So i am just looking to configure Amazon cloud front with grails version 2.3.7. I got some docs. But i want like suppose our application running on dev mode then CSS, JS , Images should use from our project and when it goes to prod mode then should use only from cdn (Amazon Cloud Front).

How to configure it.

what is the mean of a note in below url

https://github.com/tomaslin/grails-cdn-resources

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the base URL of your Amazon cloud front which will be the base URL of all the static resources of your application when running on non dev mode.

**Config.groovy**

```
// Enable for all environments
grails.resources.cdn.enabled = true
environments {
    development {
        grails.resources.cdn.enabled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes @atul, off course. You need to install that plugin.

Comment: Hi Shashank thanks. one more thing i need to know when we go to prod mode then it should take from cdn but when we in dev mode it should be take resources from localhost.

Comment: Yes, specify environments blocks in your Config.groovy to enable or disable the plugin and your problem will be solved. I've updated the answer including the example.